# Grid: Alignment by position doesn't work

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment

Let's consider a simple example

```
Grid[{ConstantArray[0, 5]}, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {3, 3}, 
 Alignment -> {0.5, 0.5}]
```

According to the documentation of Alignment,

> {x,y}   aligned at horizontal and vertical positions x and y from -1
>   to +1

but in practice, the values of positions in Alignment don't change anything.

Am I missing something, or it is a bug? If latter, what are workarounds? Mathematica 11.3

**EDIT**

Wolfram support confirmed this is unintended behavior.

Comment: Try `Alignment -> {Center, Center}`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch The problem with that is that you can't fine-tune the alignment, you only get a few predefined positions.

Comment: I think this specific syntax may not be supported in `Grid`. It does work in `Panel`, but not in `Grid`.

Comment: AlexeiBoulbitch, Unfortunately, I need to be able to use specific coordinates.
Szabolcs, It seems so, though it is not documented.

Comment: I suggest that you use the Feedback link present at the bottom of every documentation page to point out this shortcoming. Then this can at least be properly documented for future versions.

Comment: I do not have time to write an answer but I believe using `Framed` on every `Grid` item will be a good workaround. Someone can expand this into an answer: `Framed["foobar", ImageSize -> {100, 60}, Alignment -> {0.2, -0.5}, 
 FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> None]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for the answer, it worked. The only problem is that it requires manual ImageSize setting.

I have contacted Wolfram support and they confirmed this as unintended behavior.

Comment: This problem still exists in Mathematica 13.1